# Putting Numbers In Array Name

Tags: lua

Array's

```
blacklistToUse = {
 "f4blu",
 "Shifter_kart",
 "bdivo",
 "mvisiongt",
 "m3tp",
 "atsvme",
 "ktmx",
 "goldwing",
 "s500w222",
 "bs17"
}

steam:110000119172a51 = {
 "atsvme"
}
```

BlackListToUse are the custom models that users can not use. They are all locked for every player by default. steam:110000119172a51 is a user that has access to atsvme model. However, whenever I have the name as there steam id it won't run this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` in your string is going to make Lua think you're attempting to call a function named `110000119172a51` and trying to pass the variable `steam` into said function.
`110000119172a51` is an invalid name, as it starts with a number.

One work around would be:

```
whitelists = {
    ['steam:110000119172a51'] = {
        "atsvme"
    }
}

-- example use
whitelist['steam:110000119172a51'][1] -- returns the "atsvme" string
```

Wrapping the values in a table can allow you to use whatever user name string you need to.

Resource on `:` Lua syntax: [Programming in Lua: 16 – Object-Oriented Programming](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)